# Regex for Parsing HTML NewLine

Tags: c#, html, regex

```
<tr><th>Biography</th>
<td>   A bunch of random info here   <td>
```

I am trying to get all content after the biography line and the opening
tag of the next line. If the new line character not in brackets:               (?<=Biography\n).{1,50} or if it is: (?<=Biography[\n]).{1,50} I am not sure which would get all characters starting at the next line. But They both are returning nothing. What is the correct way to read the newline character in a string of HTML data?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 2):

[Never parse HTML with regex !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

A solution using a proper parser :

```
$ saxon-lint --html --xpath '//*[.="Biography"]/../td/text()' file
A bunch of random info here
```

Check https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint